# How to read an InputStream from 'in' and write an OutputStream to 'out' in a Camel route's exchange?

Tags: apache-camel, inputstream, outputstream, fileinputstream

Usually that's done with:

```
try (InputStream is = ...;
     OutputStream os = ...) {
  int b;
  while ((b = is.read()) != -1) {
    // do something with the byte
    os.write(b);
  }
}
```

In a `RouteBuilder`'s `configure()` I have the following:

```
from("file:...")
  ...
  to("direct:second")

from("direct:second")
  ...
  .process(exchange -> {
    try (InputStream is1 = 
           new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class));
         InputStream is2 = exchange.getIn().getBody(BufferedInputStream.class);
         // OutputStream os = ???
    ){
      int b;
      while ((b = [is1|is2].read()) != -1) {
        System.out.print(b); // works

        // now how to obtain the OutputStream, connect it to 'out' and write to it?

      }
    }
  })
  .to("direct:third")

from("direct:third")
  ...
```

I read docs, blogs, tutorials, SO answers about `getIn()`, `getOut()`, *Message Translator*, `transform()`, `stream:` to no avail.

**Update:** I also looked at [src/test/java/org/apache/camel/processor](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/processor), especially the `StreamCachingInOutTest`. The `Processor` there just reads an `InputStream`.

**Follow-up question:**

Is:

```
exchange.getIn().getBody(BufferedInputStream.class)
```

the same as:

```
new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class))
```

if the original `from(...)` is `"file:..."`?

#### UPDATE

I tried the following:

```
try (...;
     final OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
){
  while (b = is.read() ...) {
    ...
    os.write(b);
  }
  exchange.getOut().setBody(os, ByteArrayOutputStream.class);
}
```

The result is:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException:
  No body available of type: java.io.InputStream but has value:
    of type: org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream on: Message[].
   Caused by: No type converter available to convert from type:
     org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream to the required type:
       java.io.InputStream with value . Exchange[ID-R05377-1542620554174-0-4].
     Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException -
       No type converter available to convert from type:
         org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream to the
           required type: java.io.InputStream with value ]
at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:333)
... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException:
  No type converter available to convert from type:
    org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream to the required type:
      java.io.InputStream with value 
at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:206)
at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:115)
... 18 more
1849 [Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - Multicast] ERROR org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler  -
  Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-R05377-1542620554174-0-7 on
    ExchangeId: ID-R05377-1542620554174-0-4). Exhausted after delivery attempt:
      1 caught: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException:
        Cannot store file: <... to(...) file path of direct:third here ...>
```

#### UPDATE to the UPDATE

The exception was thrown because I used `org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream` rather than `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream`. It works with the latter and this also seems to be the answer to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

// DO NOT USE THIS IN CONJUNCTION WITH CAMEL!
//import org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream;

...    

    from(...)
      ... 
      .streamCaching()
      .process(exchange -> {
        ...
        try (final InputStream is = exchange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class);
             final OutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream(OUTSTREAM_BUFFER)) {
          while (b = is.read() ...) {

            // do something with the byte

            os.write(b);
          }
          exchange.getOut().setBody(os, OutputStream.class);
        }
      })
      ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the stream component (http://camel.apache.org/stream.html)
Example:

```
// Route messages to the standard output. 
from("direct:in")
.to("stream:out");
```

Comment: I read that page before. The 3 lines of sample code there are rudimentary, at best. I also looked at [src/test/java/org/apache/camel/processor](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/processor), especially the `StreamCachingInOutTest`. The `Processor` there just reads an `InputStream`. I'm able to do that already. Furthermore, I don't want to write to standard out. I'd like to hand over the out stream to the next `direct:` route.